# printing out source and destination ethernet addresses in C

Tags: c, networking

When I use ether_ntoa, it prints out the addresses with destination first and source second (because the first 6 bytes are for the destination). How can I reverse this order? Here's my code for the printouts:

```
 printf("%s",ether_ntoa((struct ether_addr*)packet_data)); //want to print source
 printf(" -> ");
 printf("%s \n",ether_ntoa((struct ether_addr*)packet_data)); //want to print destination
```

Comment: Did you never consider to: retrieve and store both addresses and **then** print them in any arbitrary order? As I saw in [ether_ntoa(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ether_ntoa): "The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite." Hence, you should consider to copy the retrieved contents before call `ether_ntoa()` again (e.g. with [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)).

Comment: I'd expect the two printfs to print the same address.

Comment: ah i'll try that Scheff.

Comment: ah shoot nvm, I made a mistake. It's only printing out destinations, so obviously this solution didn't work. So is there a way to store just bytes 1 to 6 (array spots 0 to 5) into something to pass to ether_ntoa. And same with bytes 6 to 12. When I try to pass array index into the ether_ntoa function, I get an invalid length error on compiling. The type of packet_data is u_char*.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printf("%s\n", ether_ntoa((struct ether_addr*) packet_data)); // prints source
printf("%s\n", ether_ntoa((struct ether_addr*) ((char*) packet_data) + 6))); // prints destination
```